# Table class generated by javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html

I need to do my homework, it's very simple, everything is right, but just the table class doesn't work.. When it's executed, the table appears, but without the classes characteriscts (like border color, width, etc.).

How can I solve this?

```js
function Gerar() {
  if (Entrada.C.value < 0 || Entrada.C.value > 10 || Entrada.L.value < 0 || Entrada.L.value > 10)
    alert("As colunas e linhas devem ser positivas e menores que 10 (dez)");
  else {
    var C, L, contl = 0,
      contc = 0;

    L = Entrada.L.value;
    C = Entrada.C.value;

    document.write("<table class='Tabela'>");

    for (i = 0; i < L; i++) {
      document.write("<tr>");

      contl += 1;

      for (j = 0; j < C; j++) {
        contc += 1;
        document.write("<td> " + contc + "," + contl + " </td>");
      }

      j = 0;

      document.write("</tr>");

      contc = 0;
    }

    document.write("</table>");
  }
}
```

```css
.Tabela {
  border-color: blue;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px;
}
```

```html
<form id="Entrada">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Coluna:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="C" size="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Linha:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="L" size="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="button" value="Ok" onclick="Gerar();" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: You might want to avoid using `document.write();` to append elements. Take a look at using [**document.createElement()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) it would also be useful if you were to create a minmal working example of what you are working with since `Entrada.C` isn't displayed in your question and the call to `Gerar()` isn't in your question source code.

Comment: Maybe this [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ypyzoLtz/) will help. Credit to **404_DisplayName** since all I have done it combine your updated source code this that answer given below.

Comment: Also if you really insist on using `document.write()` you can simple add `document.write("<style>.Tabela{border-color: blue;border-style: solid;border-width: 4px;}</style>");` just after `document.write("</table>");` [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tvmawykL/) the reason the CSS isn't applied is because `document.write()` is removing all HTML elements from the page.

Comment: Solved! Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use DOM instead of writing tags into strings.

So this is a example of a DOM based solution:

```
function createTable(intRows, intColomns)
{
    var objTable = document.createElement("table");
    objTable.setAttribute("class", "Tabela") // Here goes your class to make the css work
    for (var i = 0; i < intRows; i++) {
        var objRow = document.createElement("tr")
        for (var j = 0; j < intColomns; j++) {
            var objColomn = document.createElement("td")
            objColomn.innerHTML = j + ", " + i;
            objRow.appendChild(objColomn);
        }
        objTable.appendChild(objRow);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(objTable);
}
```

You should also change the input from "name" to "id" to make them unique

Your "Ok" button would than look something like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Ok" onclick="createTable(document.getElementById('L').value, document.getElementById('C').value);" />
```

If you realy want to keep the document.write() (Which i don't recommend) you can go for a in-line solution:

```
document.write("<table style='border-color: blue; border-style: solid; border-width: 4px;'>");
```

instead of

```
 document.write("<table class='Tabela'>");
```